# VSCode 1.73: focusing find widget darkens editor background

Tags: visual-studio-code

Beginning in VSCode 1.73, when I focus the `find` widget, the active editor background darkens.

Presumably, this is show that the `find` widget has focus, but since I go in and out of that widget 100's of times a day, the color flash is driving me crazy.

I have not been able to find a setting in `"workbench.colorCustomizations":` that addresses this.

What setting customizes color of active-editor-background-when-find-widget-focused, or reverts this behavior?

EDIT:

1. This happens with all extensions disabled.
2. Added GIF (I have my workbench customized for low contrast, but you can still see the background color change).

[image: Background color change on widget focus]

Comment: Since I can't replicate this in Stable or Insiders, I wonder if it is an extension causing this?  Maybe try the `Bisect` command.

Comment: @Mark edited to address your comment.  Any further suggestions appreciated!